# Do not put an item in list if x isn't True

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I want to add an item to my list only if a variable is true, but I want to do that in one line to not make my program longer and crappy (because I want to do that on a lot of variables). Let's say I want to return a list, but include items in it only if `x` and etc are true.

I want to use something that won't add any data to the list, because None is considered as an item.

```
# Note: The variables name may change, so please make it compatible.
return [data1 if x else None, data2 if y else None]
<< x = False, y = False = [None, None], I want []
```

**Example**

```py
# User choose if he wants data(x) by changing the default value of want_data(x)
def func(want_data1=True, want_data2=True):
    return [data1 if want_data1 else None, data2 if want_data2 else None]

print(func(False, False))
<< [None, None] # Not what I want! Excepted output is []
```

Comment: You want an empty list instead of two dummy values?

Comment: @JoeFerndz Yeah, I want an empty cell if `want_data(x)` is False

Comment: You are working with ternary expressions and they only allow the following syntax, `expr1 if cond else expr2`.. sadly an empty cell doesn't exist unless you iterate over it and choose to keep only the items that don't satisfy your conditions/mask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with ternary expressions and they only allow the following syntax, which is equivalent to `(expr1, expr2)[condition]`

```
expr1 if cond else expr2
```

Even if you try python short-circuiting, it will still return False if x is false and data1 when x is True.

```
[x and data1, y and data2]
```

For your case, you will have to do a `list comprehension` on top of the ternary opertion you have created as -

```
data1 = 'hi'
data2 = 'there'

x, y = True, False

[i for i in [data1 if x else None, data2 if y else None] if i]
```

```
['hi']
```

---

Your function with minimal modification with the above approach:

```
def func(want_data1=True, want_data2=True):
    l = [data1 if want_data1 else None, data2 if want_data2 else None]
    return [i for i in l if i]
```

Alternate approach - If you are open to numpy, its super easy to mask the list then try this:

```
import numpy as np
def func(want_data1=True, want_data2=True):
    return np.array([data1, data2])[[want_data1,want_data2]].tolist()
```

---

With a dictionary -

```
import numpy as np
def func(want_data1=True, want_data2=True):
    d = {'data1': data1, 'data2': data2}
    return dict(np.array(list(d.items()))[[want_data1,want_data2]])
```

Comment: actually we can. If you do [a for a in [False] if a], then you get []

Comment: right and you would need a list comprehension for that, exactly as my solution suggests.

Comment: Only difference is that instead of 2 separate list comprehensions I use a single one to do both the conditions together `[i for i in [data1 if x else None, data2 if y else None] if i]`

Comment: you can do a zip and combine both to create a single list comprehension like i did

Comment: yup, or you could use numpy as well, which is naturally built for such masks :)

Comment: Upvoted your answer. numpy is a good solution for this as well

Comment: Thanks! The numpy alternative is great, can we do the same thing with a dict? I.e `{'data1': data1, 'data2': data2}`? And of course add the whole item to the dict if `want_data(x)` is True

Comment: You mean keep only the (key, value) which is True?

Comment: Or you want `none` where key needs to be false?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Replace key and value with an empty cell if `want_data(x)` is False. Just like you did here but with dict, thanks!

Comment: Sure you can, Try `dict(np.array(list(d.items()))[[x,y]])`

Comment: x here is `want_data1` and y here is `want_data2` and d is the dict `{'data1': data1, 'data2': data2}`

Comment: So, just return `dict(np.array(list({'data1': data1, 'data2': data2}.items()))[[want_data1,want_data2]])`

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for something like this.

You want to check for True or False. However, the return is dependent on the parameter sent to the function.

What you can do is pair data1 & want_data1 together, and pair data2 & want_data2. The best way to pair is to use zip. Using the for loop, the pair gets picked up. You check for want_data and if True, then pass data as a result.

Below is how to get it done.

```
def check(data1, data2,x,y):

    return [a for a,b in zip((data1,data2),(x,y)) if b]

print ('1,2,True ,False', check(1,2,True,False))
print ('3,4,False, True', check(3,4,False, True))
print ('5,6,True, True ', check(5,6,True, True))
print ('7,8,False,False', check(7,8,False,False))
```

The output of this will be:

```
1,2,True ,False [1]
3,4,False, True [4]
5,6,True, True  [5, 6]
7,8,False,False []
```

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, yea. You are right. I was trying to get the initial response out so OP can comment on it. I always add details to my post. I have added comments. Thanks again for calling that out and making sure SO remains a well documented place